# Merge a Dataframe and a Series with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-merge

I got a Dataframe as below:

```
            Name     Sales
Datetime
2021-06-01  Amy      1000
2021-06-02  Amy      1500
2021-06-03  Amy      2300
2021-06-01  Joyce    3200
2021-06-02  Joyce    1422
2021-06-03  Joyce    1002
```

And I got another Series as shown below:

```
             Weather
Datetime
2021-06-01   Rain
2021-06-02   Clear
2021-06-03   Rain, Cloudy
```

What I expect is merging the dataframe and the series based on the index:

```
            Name     Sales   Weather
Datetime
2021-06-01  Amy      1000    Rain
2021-06-02  Amy      1500    Clear
2021-06-03  Amy      2300    Rain, Cloudy
2021-06-01  Joyce    3200    Rain
2021-06-02  Joyce    1422    Clear
2021-06-03  Joyce    1002    Rain, Cloudy
```

Thanks!

Comment: The second data looks like a dataframe with one column, not a Series. This is kind of important, which is it?

Comment: It is a series but I can change it to a dataframe by `second_df.to_frame()`

Comment: Alright, my answer works in any case.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you posted it, the "Series" is a one column DataFrame. Anyway, all you have to do is make an assignment. `pandas` will match the index for you.

data

```
>>> df 
             Name  Sales
Datetime                
2021-06-01    Amy   1000
2021-06-02    Amy   1500
2021-06-03    Amy   2300
2021-06-01  Joyce   3200
2021-06-02  Joyce   1422
2021-06-03  Joyce   1002
>>> df2 
                 Weather
Datetime                
2021-06-01          Rain
2021-06-02         Clear
2021-06-03  Rain, Cloudy
```

solution

```
>>> df['Weather'] = df2
>>> df 
             Name  Sales       Weather
Datetime                              
2021-06-01    Amy   1000          Rain
2021-06-02    Amy   1500         Clear
2021-06-03    Amy   2300  Rain, Cloudy
2021-06-01  Joyce   3200          Rain
2021-06-02  Joyce   1422         Clear
2021-06-03  Joyce   1002  Rain, Cloudy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for add `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1['Weather'])
```

If need add `Series`:

```
df = df.join(s.rename('Weather'))
```